# Elasticsearch, how to do matrix multiplication in Elasticsearch?

Tags: matrix, indexing, elasticsearch, multiplication

I am new to Elasticsearch, and want to do the followings:

I have to Index two large-scale matrices, I want to do two things:
1)  Index these matrix using Elasticsearch;
2)  Do a matrix multiplication on these two matrices

However, our matrix data is saved in a 3-column format instead of the typical large matrix data format, because it was processed in Hadoop/Pig: 
(row1, col1, val11), 
(row1, col2, val12), (row1, col3, val13), ……

Quesiton 1: do I have to convert the 3-column matrix data format back to the orginal big matrix format before I do the index?

Question 2:  after the matrix data index, how to do the matrix multiplication on two matrices using Elastisearch? Any sample code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Elasticsearch is supposed to do arithmetic operations, especially on matrices. However, it may be possible to use scripts for this purpose. Check these two links:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-updates.html#_using_scripts_to_make_partial_updates